# Pandas Dataframe Wildcard Values in List

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

How can I filter a dataframe to rows with values that are contained within a list? Specifically, the values in the dataframe will only be partial matches with the list and never exact match.

I've tried using pandas.DataFrame.isin but this only works if the values in the dataframe are the same as in the list.

```
list = ["123 MAIN STREET", "456 BLUE ROAD", "789 SKY DRIVE"]

df = 
   address
0  123 MAIN
1  456 BLUE
2  987 PANDA

target_df = df[df["address"].isin(list)
```

Ideally the result should be

```
target_df = 
   address
0  123 MAIN
1  456 BLUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and a simple regex using `|` to connect the terms.

```
f = '|'.join

mask = f(map(f, map(str.split, list)))
df[df.address.str.contains(mask)]
```

---

```
    address
0  123 MAIN
1  456 BLUE
```

Comment: If `df` has a row as `123 BLUE`, this `mask` will return `True`. I thought it must return `False` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ending up using for loop

```
df[[any(x in y for y in l) for x in df.address]]
Out[257]: 
    address
0  123 MAIN
1  456 BLUE
```